# Configuration for a multi-domain and multi-region web application with a single code base (next js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, configuration, next.js

We have a running website in one region and now we are going to deploy the same application in another region with the same code base. Obviously I have to make some changes for other region (like language, markup style etc).

Our Frontend is in **Nextjs** and here I am only concerned about the frontend side.

Now I have following questions in order to make both application workable efficiently with the same code base.

1. What should be the git branch structure for these two applications, whether should I maintain two different branches for two domains or same branch and have a configuration in such a way that it works for both the domains ?
2. If I should have only branch then how can I make it configurable for both the domains. 
   Let me mention some scenarios on which I need configuration.

   - I have some static text at multiple pages which will be different in both the domains.
   - markup direction is different in both. i.e RTL && LTR.
   - some components which will only appear in one region.